# Fantasy book I read in 2005ish where a empath/healer character is implied to also have a role of a more sexual nature

Tags: story-identification, books

I read a book about 10 years ago where a group of people were on some kind of quest (as one does in fantasy). It was medieval technology (swords and horses, etc). And I remember long hair, lots of forest, interaction with elves, etc. It was a series and the books were long.

One main thing I remember was that one guy had a bad day (or the whole team did, I can't remember). There's a empath healer guy whose role is kind of physiatrist/keep the peace/be wise etc. And because the other team mate has had a bad day, the healer guy kisses him to make him feel better. It also implied that more happened I think.

It seemed like it was part of his role on the team, but that role was accepted as being normal and he wasn't treated any differently from anyone else. I remember it because it was just such a different, more casual approach to sexual relations.

At the time I was reading a lot of Feist and Eddings and I'm certainly sure it wasn't either of those. It was of similar style. The book was not recently released, probably released in the past 10-20 years before I read it.

I also remember the names were odd. Not normal names but more difficult to pronounce names with apostrophes in them.

I was an oblivious teenager at the time and it was 10 years ago so I have tried my best to remember.

Comment: That's a great ID question!

Comment: @Gallifreian I'm glad you think so! I was worried it would be too vague.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you may be thinking of one of the Mercedes Lackey books. It could be either in the Mage Wars (Black Gryphon, White Gryphon, Silver Gryphon) or the Owl (Owlflight, Owlsight, Owlknight) series.

The bit that seems to relate is that there is a profession called "kestra'chern" - one who gives a client what they need rather than what they want. Treatment can include intimate relations or be as simple as massage.

The character I thought of when reading the question was Amberdrake from the Mage wars series. He is a member of a people known as Kaled'a'in. He is also a healer. The Hair thing fits as well - many of the characters in these two series have very long hair - and it tends to  be mentioned frequently.

I don't remember him kissing someone to make him feel better though. I also don't recall any elves in these books. However lots of the names have apostrophes in them.

Comment: This is the series I was thinking of also. I think that the people who are trained in massage are the ones who also have the possibility of taking the 'healing' further... I remember that in one of the books there was jealousy amongst the masseurs over who got to work on a particular client.

Comment: The jealousy was in the first book-The Black Gryphon.

Comment: Thanks! I definitely read the owl_ series at that time too. It's very familiar. I am pretty sure the character was Silverfox. Since he was in the mage winds series, that must be it.

Comment: I found the passage! It's actually in owlknight so well done! See my answer :)

Answer (score 3):

I found the exact passage I remember! It's from Owlknight by Mercedes Lackey. user22225 narrowed down the author and series. I definitely remember that Silverfox was one of the parties involved. Here's the passage, it's at the end of chapter 3:

> Very sensible of you - and I’m only reminding you of the worst
>   possible situation.” Silverfox reached over and took his hand,
>   squeezing it reassuringly. “We could have the very opposite here, with
>   both of them wanting a committed relationship, and both holding back
>   because of some idealistic nonsense or other - ”
>
> “Like, for instance?” Firesong put a teasing note into his voice,
>   knowing what Silverfox was likely to say. “Idealism is always nonsense
>   when it isn’t your idealism, eh?”
>
> “Pest. Like, for instance, that they both are under the illusion that
>   all successful relationships have to be lifebonds,” Silverfox replied.
>
> “You mean they don’t?” Firesong asked innocently.
>
> “Oh, no, no, no. Spells aren’t needed to make magic, and lifebonds
>   aren’t needed to make love. Here - ” Silverfox put his drink down, and
>   stood up in a single fluid, gliding motion, to lean over Firesong’s
>   chair. His long hair made a curtain that shut out the rest of the
>   world. “Allow me to demonstrate. . . .”

It was between Silverfox and Firesong, who ready have an established relationship (or, go on to have one). So Silverfox wasn't really "on the job" as it were.